# Page load to new page when using compare and don't compare?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

i created calculation page. in my page Two page home page and results page. home page click  submit button .that button redirect to defaults_results page load.

Now my Concept i have using in code  “Compare” “Don’t Compare” .when compare is active its hidden some input value .when don't compare active  that time input fields not hidden. i have used this concept script:

script:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#DontCompare").hide();
        $("#btnDontCompare").click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass("active").next().slideToggle("fast");
            if ($.trim($(this).text()) === 'Compare') {
                $("#DontCompare").show();
                $(this).text('Dont Compare');
                $('#txtComparsion').val('1');
            } else {
                $(this).text('Compare');
                $("#DontCompare").hide();
                $('#txtComparsion').val('0');
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

compare and don't compare code:

```
  <div id="DontCompare">

              <div class="row">
            <label style="text-align: center;font-weight:600;">
              <input type="radio" name="CompareLoan" id="radioCompareLoan" /> Compare All Loans Above  
                </label>
              </div>


        <div class="col-md-2  padding-rht ">
   <input name="noyears"  class="txt" id="noyears" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" value="30" />  
               </div>

         <div class="col-md-3">
  <p> <input name="interestrate" class="txt"  id="interestrate" type="text" size="6" maxlength="6" style="width:75%" />%</p>
                 </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 padding-Zero" >
   <input id="downpaymentCompare" type="text" class="txt" size="8" maxlength="8"/>
                     </div>

                     </div>
                    </div>
               <div class="col-md-6">                             
                <div class="row" >
         <label style="text-align: center;font-weight:600;"><input type="radio" name="CompareLoan" checked id="radio1" /> Compare Primary Loan Above To The Loan Below
                  </label>
                    </div>

                                       <p></p>
                 <div class="row margin-side">
             <div class="col-md-2  padding-Zero">
    <input  class="txt" type="text" id="CompareUpfront" size="3" maxlength="3" />

             </div>


        <div class="col-md-1 padding-lft" style="right:13px;top:3px">
                 <input id="chkloanUFtoLoan" checked type="checkbox" /> 
              </div>

                        <div class="col-md-2 padding-Zero">
   <input  type="text" size="8" id="CompareMonthly" class="txt" maxlength="8" />
                                            </div>
                       <div class="col-md-2 padding-Zero" >
     <input type="text" size="8" class="txt" maxlength="8" id="ComparessMonthly" />
                                            </div>
```

Now created New page  scenario1.  i  need to load this page when compare active  and also input value value hidden that time  i want load this page?  if click compare  its change to don't compare value are  input fields showing  .this time i want load my old page defaults_Results page? how i will create this one?  even i have tired  this script?

```
 <script>
   document.getElementById("Button4").onclick = function () {

       if($('#txtComparsion').val() == 0)
       {

         $('.frmCalculator').attr("action","/default_results.php");

    alert($('#txtComparsion').val());
       }
    else
    {
        alert($('#txtComparsion').val());
        $('.frmCalculator').attr("action","/scenario1.php");

    }
   };
</script>
```

please anyone help me out?  give some  idea about it?